# Binary Format Deserialization

Tags: c#, c, .net, binaryformatter

I have two programs one is written in C and another is in C#. In the C# program, I am using `BinaryFormatter().Serialize()` method to serialize a data model and then send the serialized binary stream to C program through a TCP socket. Now In the C program, I want to extract the data so that I want to know the format of how `BinaryFormatter().Serialize()` generates the byte stream. I want to write a deserializer function in C for regenerating data serialized by `BinaryFormatter().Serialize()` in C#. Is there any documentation or information available for this?

Comment: What is the exact data (before serialization) that you send? Do you really need to send a binary serialization? Why not a text-based format like JSON, or just plain simple unformatted text (if that's what you're sending)?

Comment: Actually, the purpose is not to send data but to understand the format of binary serialization.

Comment: So this is more about curiosity, and not an actual problem you need to solve? Then please [edit] your question to say so. Otherwise, in its current form, your question is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: It's not about curiosity, I am developing a performance-intensive application where I have to use binary serialization

Comment: For documentation purpose and deep dive on how things work in .NET (4.5.1 to 4.8) i invite you to bookmark [Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/). It contains most if not all source code from every .NET objects. Specially for the `BinaryFormatter` [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryformatter.cs,c19170bda56bc560) would be the source code on how it works. You should specify which version of .NET you are using as it would result in actual correct answer instead of guesses

Comment: Did you *measure* that there is a relevant performance difference between serialization to/from binary vs. text format? Did you notice that `BinaryFormatter().Serialize()` is declared obsolete? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete

Comment: Also if i were to serialize data between C and C# i would use a better format that has faster serialization/deserialization. Example xml serialization is much better nowadays than binary serialization in speed. File is bigger but CPU time is about 15%-20% faster. As for other library cross platform out of all those i know Protobuf is the speed king but it's more complex to work with

Comment: Don't write code like this yourself. Use something like BSON or ProtoBuf if you think binary serialization is the sh*t. It's probably faster and safer than homegrown.

Comment: "I am developing a performance-intensive application where I have to use binary serialization" - there's a difference between "needing an efficient binary format" and "needing to use BinaryFormatter".

Comment: Have you *measured* that possible text-base serialization and deserialization is a key top bottleneck in the system? Or do you only *think* it might be? Always start simple, then measure to see if it is Good Enough™ (which often it is) or not. Only if the measurement fall outside of actual requirements, or start to affect other systems, do exact profiling to find the top one or two bottlenecks and fix those first. If it turns out to actually be the serialization/deserialization, then use existing libraries and solutions rather than make your own.

Comment: Also, in addition to the considerations above: if you really have hard requirements to the performance of used serialization, I'd fire up benchmark projects to measure different possible candidates and see if _any_ of those actually meet the required numbers. If your best option is still too slow, you now find yourself on another level of problems.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to deserialize data from BinaryFormatter in C would be to invoke the .net framework and use BinaryFormatter.

But this is really not the best way to transfer data over the network. BinaryFormatter is slow, insecure, and fragile. The format might even change between two .net versions.

A much better way would be to use a serialization format intended for communication between different systems. I have used Protobuf .net with good result, and C should have some protobuf implementation. BSON, textbased formats like json/xml might also be alternatives.

If you are writing a "performance intensive" application it is probably a good idea to take a look at a few [benchmarks](https://github.com/Alois-xx/SerializerTests/) before choosing a library, or do your own performance testing. In the benchmarks I have seen, BinaryFormatter is often the slowest alternative, so it is not a good choice if you are concerned about performance. The only reason I would ever use it is for reading data from some legacy system.